# php to access shared smb folder (user/password protected)

Tags: php, apache, wamp, samba, smb

1. WAMP server
2. PHP fopen function needs to open file in shared folder //server/folder1/file1.txt
3. php has SYSTEM user permisions, but shared folder is visible only for userX/password

how can i open this remote file inside php script?

Answer (score 4):

You can specify the username and password in the path: `//user:password@server/folder1/file1.txt`

Answer (score 3):

I had the exact same problem and Sjoerd's answer didn't work for me on Windows.

I wrote a mounting function in PHP which basically [exec](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php)s:

```
net use "\\smbserver\share" /user:"myuser" "mypassword" /persistent:no
```

Then you can normally access paths like `\\smbserver\share/path/file`.

This works for all functions specified in the [options table for file wrappers](https://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.file.php):

- Allows Reading
- Allows Writing
- Allows Appending
- Allows Simultaneous Reading and Writing
- Supports stat()
- Supports unlink()
- Supports rename()
- Supports mkdir()
- Supports rmdir()

This works perfectly stable on remote shares but didn't work for me when I used localhost with apache as SYSTEM.

Don't forget to unmount afterwards by `exec`ing:

```
net use "\\smbserver\share" /delete /yes
```

I hope this helps.